# One of my headings is mysteriously coming up as a link in my CPT Archive

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, taxonomy, archives

One of my term headings is randomly injected with  tags and is coming up as a link in my archive.

This behavior can be seen at https://summithmeinc.com/faq/.

I've examined my function that replaces the default loop a number of times and can't figure out why it is doing this. In the function, I get the respective term and echo it with `<h2>` tags, but the one instance is coming up w/ `<a>` tags inside the `<h2>` tags.

```
function smt_faq_output() {

    $faq_cat_terms = get_terms('faq_category');

    foreach($faq_cat_terms as $faq_cat_term) {

        $faq_cat_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'faq',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  =>  'faq_category',
                    'field'     =>  'slug',
                    'terms'     =>  array( $faq_cat_term->slug),
                    'operator'  =>  'In'
                    )
                )
            ));

        echo '<h2>'. $faq_cat_term->name .'</h2>';

        if($faq_cat_query->have_posts()): 

            echo '<div class="qa-accordion">';

            $i = 1;

            while($faq_cat_query->have_posts()): $faq_cat_query->the_post();

                echo '<div class="qa-set">';
                echo '<a class="question" href="#answer-'. $i .'-'. $faq_cat_term->name .'">';
                echo the_field('question');
                echo '</a>';
                echo '<div id="answer-'. $i .'-'. $faq_cat_term->name .'" class="answer">';
                echo the_field('answer');
                echo '</div><!-- end answer block --></div><!--end qa_set div-->';

                $i++;

            endwhile;

            echo '</div><!-- end qa_accordion -->';

        endif;

    $faq_cat_query = null;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

The following is the accordion.js script I use to add the functionality to the accordion items.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.qa-accordion .question').removeClass('active');
        $('.qa-accordion .answer').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }
    $('.question').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
        if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.qa-accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
        }
    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The only thing I can think is that it's somehow related to strange behavior from the query because I'm foregoing the default loop w/ a more customized query to include the term headings/organizational output. I've since learned to use pre_get_posts to edit the default queries, but I wasn't sure how to do this for this type of output due to the need for more functionality from the default loop in this archive.

Is there something I'm missing here as to why this is randomly being displayed as a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query here is fine. It's the only way to split it up into sections like that, but it belongs on a page template, not the archive. Archives should always use the main loop for its contents. Make the post type private to turn off the archive and just use your queries in a page template.

But for the tag issue, queries are never going to insert markup like that. Queries don't output any markup at all outside what's in the content. Your problem is that the content in the previous question, "What insurances are currently accepted by Summit?" isn't closing a link tag properly:

```
or please <a href="https://summithmeinc.com/services/insurance-billing/">refer to our page on insurance billing for a list of current insurance companies we work with<a/>.
```

That `<a/>` at the end needs to be `</a>`.

Comment: Doh! Great eye Jacob. Also, I’ll get this (and some of my other customized archive queries) changed over to templates in my next update since it will hopefully improve performance a bit. The input is very much appreciated. Thanks man.